# After folder compact, emails has disappeared from Outlook Express 6

Tags: outlook-express

After Outlook Express 6 asked me to compact my mail folders, I found that more than 6 months of mails has disappeared. (They are not in the deleted folder.) Where would it have gone, and how can I fix this problem?

Comment: I don't know what other ways of doing it there are, but I heard you can achieve this using the program DBXtract.

Answer (score 1):

Got this problem solved.  Had a look in the Recycle Bin, and found the Inbox.bak file that Outlook Express [apparently](http://discussions.virtualdr.com/showthread.php?248614-Lost-Inbox-Emails-After-Compacting-Outlook-Express) makes sometimes before it does a compact.  Moved it to Outlook Express' store folder, renamed it do Inbox.dbx, overriding original. After starting Outlook Express again all was well.

See [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/270670) for instructions on how to find your store folder.

Comment: You got very lucky! It’s very fortunate that you happened to check your Recycle Bin in time before it was emptied and happened to have a copy there. I have never seen OE put anything in the Recycle Bin. During compaction, it creates a `.dbt` file in the message store, not a `.bak` file, so you may want to check if you have any plugins installed.